# Change dropzone default file name with Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade, dropzone.js

I want to use dropzone.js to upload images in my application , I'm using laravel 4.2 , This is my code in the view :

```
{{ Form::open(array('class'=>'dropzone', 'id'=>'my-awesome-dropzone' ,'files'=> true , 'method' => 'post' ,'route' => '/')) }}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ $errors->first('title','<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">:message</div>') }}
        {{ Form::text('title',null , array('placeholder'=>'title' , 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ $errors->first('image','<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">:message</div>') }}
        {{ Form::label('image', 'Image') }}
        {{ Form::file('image') }}

        </div>
        {{ Form::submit('create' , array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

And this is my code to upload image in the controller

```
if (Input::hasFile('image'))
            {

                $file = Input::file('image');
                $timestamp = (new DateTime)->getTimestamp();
                $imageFileName = Helpers::getFriendlyURL(Input::get('title'),$timestamp) .'.png';
                $file->move('uploads/'. Auth::user()->id .'/', $imageFileName);
                $image = Image::make(sprintf('uploads/'. Auth::user()->id .'/%s', $imageFileName))->fit(900, 300)->save();
            }
```

I have 2 Qestions :

1 - How to change the default file name 'file' of dropzone to 'image' ?
[image]

2 - the submit button comes on and the browse button appears ?